# Defining a specific transitive property as a rule in OWLReady2

Tags: python, rdf, owl, owlready

I am trying to build a knowledge graph using the [OWLReady2](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) libray for Python. Before, I became very familiar with rdflib, but ontologies are far more complex…

The specific example I am trying to do is:

- Define persons
- Define photos
- Provide facts about which photo depicts which persons
- Infere which persons are depicted together with which other persons

My working example provides all the definitions needed:

```py
from owlready2 import *

onto = get_ontology("urn:test")


with onto:
    class Person(Thing): pass
    class Photo(Thing): pass
    class depicts(Photo >> Person): pass
    class depiction(Person >> Photo): inverse_property = depicts
    class depicted_with(Person >> Person): pass
    depicted_with_imp = Imp()
    depicted_with_imp.set_as_rule("Person(?a), depiction(?a, ?p), depicts(?p, ?b) -> depicted_with(?a, ?b)")

pe1 = Person(name="Person 1")
pe2 = Person(name="Person 2")
pe3 = Person(name="Person 3")

ph1 = Photo()
ph2 = Photo()

ph1.depicts = [pe1, pe2]
ph2.depicts = [pe2, pe3]

sync_reasoner_pellet(infer_property_values = True, infer_data_property_values = True)

assert pe1.depicted_with == [pe2]
assert pe2.depicted_with == [pe1, pe3]
assert pe3.depicted_with == [pe2]
```

What I cannot wrap my head around is how to write the `depicted_with` property, so that the inferred property will be created when reasoning.

Comment: "Infere which persons are depicted together with which other persons" - that sounds more like the need for an SWRL rule than simple OWL axioms

Comment: @UninformedUser Yes, I figure that as well. However, no success in that either. I have updated the question with an SWRL rule, but the properties still remain empty.